# Selecting only rows containing at least the given elements in SQL

Tags: sql

Using PostgreSQL, and given the following sample table, how do I select all parents that have at least a child 10 **and** a child 20?

```
 parent | child
--------+-------
      1 |    10
      1 |    20
      1 |    30
      2 |    10
      2 |    20
      3 |    10
```

In other words, this is the expected result:

```
 parent
--------
      1
      2
```

In general, how do I select all parents that have at least **all** of the given children *x1*, *x2*, ..., *xn*? What is the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: @liszt...your quetsion is not clear..Provide sample result data you require..

Comment: Can you please post some sample output?

Comment: Sorry about that; I've added the expected result.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT parent FROM table WHERE child IN(10,20)
GROUP BY parent 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT child)>=2
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/45572/2)

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what your asking. However, I shall give it a crack.

If you're going to manually define the children you can do a simple select statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent
FROM table1
WHERE child IN ('10', '20')
```

This would select all Parents that have 10 or 20 as there child. To add more, just add the number to the IN() part.

If however you want to do this for a large number of children or perhaps an unknown number of children then you can create a temp table to store the children search values and join it to your main table. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE #SearchChildren
(
    Child int
)
```

Then input your search values into #SearchChildren. Need to know more about what your doing to do this bit.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.parent
FROM table1 as a
JOIN #SearchChildren as s
ON a.child = s.Child
```

Without knowing more about what your trying to do it's difficult to give a full answer but hopefully this helps.